# Import a font in symfony project

Tags: symfony, fonts

I try to add a font in my project symfony I download the font on the site dafont

I added this code in my Css file

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: ceria-lebaran;
     src: url('/assets/composants/sliders/css/Ceria Lebaran.otf');
 }


 lbad-carousel-text h1 {
 font-family: 'Ceria Lebaran', sans-serif;
 font-size:38px;
 color:black;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 }
```

but it does not work

please help

Answer (score 1):

try it like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ceria';
  src: url({{ asset('composants/sliders/css/Ceria\\ Lebaran.otf') }}) format('opentype');
}

body {
  font-family: 'ceria', sans-serif;
}
```

Since your font file has a space in the name, you need to scape it with `\\`